# Is it possible to connect to the opensource self hosted InfluxDB OSS v2 to Apache Superset?

Tags: docker, sqlalchemy, influxdb, apache-superset, influxdb-2

I am trying to connect Apache Superset to the InfluxDB 2 OSS. Both Apache superset and InfluxDB are running on a docker container in my local machine.
Is it possible to connect to the opensource self hosted version of InfluxDB from Apache Superset?

Tried this sqlalchemy url

datafusion+flightsql://localhost:8086?database=bucket-1&token=

But received ERROR: Could not load database driver: BaseEngineSpec

I expect to connect to the database and visualize the data using Apache Superset.